# Sum of another column MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this following SQL code:

```
select user_id, quest_registration.quest_id, count(quest.quest_id), quest.quest_rarity, 
       case quest.quest_rarity 
       when 1 then count(user_id) * 1 
       when 2 then count(user_id) * 2 
       when 3 then count(user_id) * 3 
       when 4 then count(user_id) * 4 
       when 5 then count(user_id) * 5 
       end as points, 
       SUM(points)
from quest_registration 
inner join quest 
on quest_registration.quest_id = quest.quest_id
where user_id=2 AND quest_registration.date_completed is not null
group by quest.quest_rarity;
```

I want to display the sum of points column. How do I do that?

SOLVED
NEW PROBLEM

I have this following create function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION points_earned (u_id INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt1 INT DEFAULT 0;
    select SUM(points)
    from (select case quest.quest_rarity 
            when 1 then count(user_id) * 1 
            when 2 then count(user_id) * 2 
            when 3 then count(user_id) * 3 
            when 4 then count(user_id) * 4 
            when 5 then count(user_id) * 5 
        end as points
        from quest_registration inner join quest 
        on quest_registration.quest_id=quest.quest_id
        where user_id=2 AND quest_registration.date_completed is not null
        group by quest.quest_rarity) x;
```

```
RETURN cnt1;
```

END $$

This create function code gives me an error of: ERROR 1415 (0A000) at line 3: Not allowed to return a result set from a function

What does this mean?

Comment: That's what `SUM(points)` does. What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I solved it already. But that code gives me an error that points is not a valid column.

Comment: You can't access an alias in the same `SELECT` statement that defines it. You need to turn it into a subquery.

Comment: What column should `SUM(points)` be grouped by ?

Comment: @Barmar yes. that is how i solved it. I turned it into a subquery. Please help me with the other problem. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You never put the result of the query into `cnt1` so why are you returning it?

Comment: There are lots of similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmysql%5d%20%22not%20allowed%20to%20return%20a%20result%20set%20from%20a%20function%22

Comment: Yes. My bad. I forgot to put it. Still the error persists.

Comment: When you get an error message, you should try searching for it here or with google. That's how I did it.

Comment: i think you needs to used SUM(x.points) it helps you to solved the error but your returning cnt1 which default 0 why??

Comment: Not allowed to return a resultset from a function: Functions for inline use in a query, and have to return a single value. If you want to get a resultset as return, use a procedure instead.

Comment: @VishalJAIN i didn't put x still worked. unless you have multiple columns from multiple tables. i guess but anyway thanks to you too! :D